# Meteor - Ckeditor Integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, ckeditor

I'm not sure if there has been a change in the way Meteor loads items, or the way it handles jquery, but I'm having an awful lot of trouble getting ckeditor to come up.

Main Template (Iron-router):

```
<template name="layout">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
.....
</template>
```

Independent Editor Template:

```
<template name="editor">
    <div class="editor_container">
        <textarea class="editor"></textarea>
    </div>
</template>
```

Ckeditor located at `public/js/ckeditor`, any time I try to do the `Template.editor.rendered()` technique, or even just trying to type `$('.editor').ckeditor();` into the console, I get an error of:

```
$('.editor').ckeditor();
VM48825:2 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking the `<head>` section out of the layout template. Reading here I believe the `<head>` section is treated specially be meteor (see: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) and that it being inside a template may be causing the JS to actually not be loaded. Just a guess though.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<template name="layout">
.....
</template>
```

Comment: Ah yes I've tried that as well, just putting the script tags directly into the template and the same thing happened.

Comment: No, script tags should not be in the template. I think that is the problem. I'll edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Marvelous, it was indeed the head tags that got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IRLibLoader` from `iron:router` into the `onBeforeAction` like this.

```
Router.route('/editor', {
  name: 'editor',
  template: 'layout',
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    var ckEditor = IRLibLoader.load('/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
    var adapter = IRLibLoader.load('/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js');
    if(ckEditor.ready() && adapter.ready()){
      console.log('The 2 JS just finish load');
      this.next(); // Render the editor page

      if(Meteor.isClient){
        Template.editor.rendered = function(){
          $('.editor').ckeditor();
          console.log("loading coeditor when template fully rendered");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Alternative on the main `layout` you can use this.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<template name="layout">
 {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="editor">
    <div class="editor_container">
        <textarea class="editor"></textarea>
    </div>
</template>
```

And do the same rendered function

```
Template.editor.rendered = function(){
   $('.editor').ckeditor();

   //or make a little delay (1sec) 
   Meteor.setTiemout(function(){
    $('.editor').ckeditor();
   },100)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code :

- You can't put `<head>` sections inside another template, it must be done outside all templates.
- The path to your JS files are broken, you must prepend a slash to them to reference files in the public directory.
- Loading scripts in `<head>` sections is not a good idea because they will be loaded when your app first loads for every user, even if they never use the editor.

Here is a solution where we load every scripts asynchronously using jQuery promises when the editor template is rendered, and only then initialize the CKEditor.

```
Template.editor.rendered=function(){
  var template=this;
  $.when(
    $.getScript("/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"),
    $.getScript("/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js")
  ).done(function(){
    template.$(".editor").ckeditor();
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I do understand what you're doing and progress has been made. I can now see CKEDITOR from the console, but not the jquery adaptation script.